# How can I set value to Html hidden fields from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html, controls, field, hidden

I have scenario, where there are html hidden fields, the page can be redirected to itself, with parameters, I have sessions too. Now depending on session value I want to set some hidden values, so that it can be picked up from javascript and can do certain operation. But, the problem is I have no idea about how to get/ set values into html controls using asp.net, and also do not know whether this is possible or not.
Please note, it is imperative that I need some way to hold some data that can be set using asp.net and can be picked up by javascript. Since session can not be used for this purpose, so I need some other way.

Please enlighten me!

Thanks and regards
Arunendra

Comment: Is it necessary to use hidden fields?  Any reason you can't just output javascript variables directly?

Comment: Hi
I have ajax to get some data from another page, and that data is displayed, the user can click and the same page will reload to display some more information, so I need the javascript to know that the hidden fields are having some value so that the user can see the same elements which they clicked to reach the search results, otherwise those sections will be reset normally, since the page is reloading, so I need someway so that the asp.net and javascript can access same elements to get/set values.

Thanks 
arunendra

Answer (score 1):

You can use:
`Request["fieldname"]` to access hidden fields from your .net code.  For example:

```
Request["myfield"] = "some value";
```

Comment: Hi
Thanks for such a quick reply, I have tried it right now, as I am using vb.net I put the code like Request("myfield") = "some value", but it is giving a blue line throughout the line, saying "Property item is read only"

What to do next ...

Thanks and regards
Arunendra